# R Shiny - Unable to display data table in mainpanel based on "selectInput" user selection

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to display a table in the mainpanel based on selection by the user from drop down.

Ex. The "selectInput" dropdown will have the values from table789 (options are 123, xyz, ...)
If user selects 123 then "table123" has to be displayed else "table456" to be displayed.

I'm very new to shiny, tried the below and got **"attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'"** error. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Can anyone help?

Server:

```
    server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$outputtable = reactive({ifelse(input$selction == '123', DT::renderDataTable(table123), DT::renderDataTable(table456)) })
  
}
```

UI:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(selectInput("selction", "Select", choices = table789$column1, selected = "xyz")),
  
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("select", DT::dataTableOutput("outputtable")),
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing things up here, you shouldn't be putting `renderDataTable` into `reactive`, this should work:

```
library(shiny)

table789 <- mtcars
table456 <- iris
table123 <- mtcars
table789$column1 <- sample(c("123","456"),nrow(table789),replace = T)


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    sidebarPanel(selectInput("selection", "Select", choices = unique(table789$column1), selected = "xyz")),
    
    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("select", 
                     DT::dataTableOutput("outputtable")
            )
        )
    )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    data <- eventReactive(input$selection,{
        if(input$selection == "123"){
            return (table123)
        }
        table456
    })
    
    output$outputtable <- DT::renderDataTable(
        data()
    )
    
}

#Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It worked !!! Thank you so much for the swift response !!! But really don't understand why "ifelse" don't work in this scenario. What is the difference between them? and also you have used "return()" if condition is TRUE but not for FALSE condition. Can you please explain?

Comment: If you look at the `?ifelse`, you will see that `ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test ...` its not a `dataframe`